# Cookies only set on local machine

Tags: python, linux, cookies, server, python-requests

I am trying to fetch an endpoint which needs multiple cookies to work.
So my request looks like this:

```py
    cookiestring="key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;"
    headers = {"Cookie" : cookiestring}
    url = f"https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name={market_hash_name}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    print(response.status_code)
```

When executing this on my laptop (in which I can log in via the browser to get the key-value pairs for the cookies) it works fine. Using PostMan, the request also works fine.

When deploying the script to a root-server (ubuntu) It won't work anymore and I have no Idea why. The code is copy pasted and the exact same.

Any Ideas on how to fix this or to further debug?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How exactly have you deployed the server to an Ubuntu server? Have you deployed it to a cloud service? Have you used a Virtual Machine (VM)? Or, have you just used a separate device? Please let me know, it could help debug this situation.

Comment: It is a cloud server hosted by IONOS